# Using a formula in a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a formula in a range of cells but I get the formula in that cell and not the results of the formula.

I tried a couple of different ways.

The first script I tried entered the formula all the way down the column until the last row value: -

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
Range("DO22:DO" & LastRow).Formula = "IF=COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Major Variance"")>0,""Major Variance"",IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Minor Variance"")>0,""Minor Variance"",""On Track""))"
```

This is the other script I tried but this puts the formula only in the first row of the range: -

```
Dim LastRow As Long  
Dim Rng As Range
Range("DO22:DO" & LastRow).Select
For Each Rng In Range("DO22:DO" & LastRow)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "IF=COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Major Variance"")>0,""Major Variance"",IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Minor Variance"")>0,""Minor Variance"",""On Track""))"
Next Rng
```

Edit 1

I have made a change to the code as per someone's answer but I am now getting an run-time error 'Application-defined or object defined error.

It only seems to happen when I add the extra = in front of the If.  The error appears on the line

```
Rng.Formula = "=IF=COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Major Variance"")>0,""Major Variance"",IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Minor Variance"")>0,""Minor Variance"",""On Track""))"
```

Here is the edited script: -

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

Range("DO22:DO" & LastRow).Select
For Each Rng In Range("DO22:DO" & LastRow).Cells
    Rng.Formula = "=IF=COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Major Variance"")>0,""Major Variance"",IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Minor Variance"")>0,""Minor Variance"",""On Track""))"
    Rng.Value = Rng.Value
Next Rng
```

Comment: Your formula must begin with the **=** sign

Comment: It is unclear on why you are writing the same formula into each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a malformed [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb) and [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

```
'target formula "=IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU99, "Major Variance"), "Major Variance", =IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU99, "Minor Variance"), "Minor Variance", "On Track"))
rng.Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & lastRow & ", ""Major Variance""), ""Major Variance"", " & _
               "IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & lastRow & ", ""Minor Variance""), ""Minor Variance"", " & _
               """On Track""))"
rng = rng.Value
```

Note that if both Major Variance and Minor Variance exist, then Major Variance takes precedence.

To put this formula into each row and modify the row each time in a loop, the code would look like this.

```
Dim lastRow As Long, rng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")       '<~~ you should know what worksheet you are on!
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rng In .Range("DO22:DO" & lastRow)
        rng.Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(AS" & rng.Row & ":AU" & rng.Row & ", ""Major Variance""), ""Major Variance"", " & _
                       "IF(COUNTIF(AS" & rng.Row & ":AU" & rng.Row & ", ""Minor Variance""), ""Minor Variance"", " & _
                       """On Track""))"
        rng.Value = rng.Value
    Next rng
End With
```

But you can also put the formula into all of the cells at once like this.

```
Dim lastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")       '<~~ you should know what worksheet you are on!
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("DO22:DO" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU22, ""Major Variance""), ""Major Variance"", " & _
                       "IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU22, ""Minor Variance""), ""Minor Variance"", " & _
                       """On Track""))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: this now sort of works but it enters the same value all the way down the column.  What I want is to check each row again the if statement enter the result in column DO then move on to the next row.

Comment: Yes. I mentioned in a comment to the original question that it appeared that you were writing the same formula into every cell but it is not clear on what you **want** to do. You probably want to write each new row as a countif for that row only or maybe a progressive build up of rows. So far what you are attempting is not clear.

Comment: what I am trying to do it get the overall value of a row using the if statement.  I have three columns and need to get the overall value for each row.  The trouble with doing an if statement for each row is that the last row number will change every time I need to run the script and also it could be as long as 200 rows.  Have I explained it any better, I can add an example in to the question if it helps

Comment: I've shown a row-by-row formula in a loop and all-at-once above.

Comment: Thanks very much for that it works.  I can understand what you've done :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using activecell in the 2nd one so it will only be in the active cell if not selected.  so you need to change your loop to be

```
 For Each Rng In Range("DO22:DO" & LastRow).cells
```

and then

```
rng.Formula = "=IF=COUNTIF(AS22:AU" & LastRow & " ,""=Major Variance"")....
```

then

```
rng.value=rng.value
```

also, in the 2nd one, youre not setting LastRow.

Comment: I have made those changes to my scripting please see amendments in the question. I am now getting a run-time error